# Drawing textured quads OpenGL not working

Tags: java, opengl, png, textures, lwjgl

I am trying to render a group of textured quads.

I can get colored quads to render, but not textured ones (screen comes up empty.)

I am using LWJGL and PNGDecoder.

Code for initializing my OGL:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Code for decoding my image:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = null;
InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename);
try {
    buffer = decodeStreamToBuffer(in);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
return buffer;
```

My `decodeStreamToBuffer(InputStream in)`:

```
PNGDecoder decoder;
ByteBuffer buf = null;
try {
    decoder = new PNGDecoder(in);

    buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*decoder.getWidth()*decoder.getHeight());
    decoder.decode(buf, decoder.getWidth()*4, Format.RGBA);
    buf.flip();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return buf;
```

My rendering code:

```
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f); //Still there to test color quads.

    // draw quad
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glTranslatef(screencenter.getX(), screencenter.getY(), 0);
        GL11.glScalef(1f, 0.5f, 1f);
        GL11.glRotatef(camRotation, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        GL11.glTranslatef(-screencenter.getX(), -screencenter.getY(), 0);

        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);

            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex2f(32, 0);

            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL11.glVertex2f(32, 32);

            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            GL11.glVertex2f(0, 32);

        GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

When I leave the texture binding out and change the `GL_TEXTURE_2D` to `GL_MODELVIEW` it all works... but with color instead of a texture. Am I making a noob mistake here?

Comment: Neither one of those enumerants is valid for a call to `glBegin (...)`. You are supposed to pass the primitive type (e.g. GL_QUADS)

Comment: Well, that's odd, since I copied and pasted that part from a tutorial, initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong `GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

The `glBegin` method an `primitive mode` `GLenum`.

Thereby you either use:

- `GL_POINTS`
- `GL_LINES`
- `GL_LINE_STRIP`
- `GL_LINE_LOOP`
- `GL_TRIANGLES`
- `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`
- `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`
- `GL_QUADS`
- `GL_QUAD_STRIP`
- `GL_POLYGON`

The mode you use specify what you are rendering. In your case you would code `GL_QUADS` So to fix your code you need to replace `GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);` with `GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);`.

#### Extra

Also take in mind that the `glVertex`,  `glNormal`,  `glTexCoord`, etc. Methods are deprecated and should not be used. You are suppose to use VBOs and Shaders. *Though if you are learning OpenGL then keep using the deprecated methods since they are good and easy to use when learning!*

Comment: Thanks for taking your time with me. I'll try it and then update with my results.